# The installation of Python and Selenium is not working

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am using:

- Python 2.5
- OS: [Windows Vista](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista)

There was an error when I tried to install Selenium 2.13 using

```
pip install -U Selenium
```

Output:

```
Downloading/unpacking Selenium
Downloading selenium-2.13.1.tar.gz (3.3Mb): 3.3Mb downloaded
Running setup.py egg_info for package Selenium
warning: no files found matching 'docs\api\py\index.rst'
c:\Python25\lib\distutils\dist.py:263: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'src_root'
  warnings.warn(msg)
Downloading/unpacking rdflib==3.1.0 (from Selenium)
Downloading rdflib-3.1.0.tar.gz (249Kb): 249Kb downloaded
Running setup.py egg_info for package rdflib
Installing collected packages: Selenium, rdflib
Found existing installation: selenium 2.13.1
Uninstalling selenium:
  Successfully uninstalled selenium
Running setup.py install for Selenium
warning: no files found matching 'docs\api\py\index.rst'
c:\Python25\lib\distutils\dist.py:263: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'src_root'
  warnings.warn(msg)
c:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:668: Warning: 'with' will  become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6
File "c:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 668 with  open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Found existing installation: rdflib 3.1.0
Uninstalling rdflib:
Successfully uninstalled rdflib
Running setup.py install for rdflib
Successfully installed Selenium rdflib
Cleaning up...
```

So I downloaded the Selenium 2.13 package manually and copied the *selenium.py* file into *c:/python25/lib/*. However, when I try to import *webdriver* from within Python it gives me the following error:

```
python F:\Selenium\localtest2.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Selenium\localtest2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ImportError: cannot import name webdriver
```

Is there a problem with the Selenium install or is there something wrong that I am doing? Maybe copying just the *selenium.py* file is stupid?

I followed the tutorial given [here](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_installing_python_driver_client.html).

In the above tutorial, how can I do the following?

"Add to your test’s path the file selenium.py"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently Selenium 2.13 has a requirement of Python 2.6, given the syntax error (dependency: 'with').

You have an option to possibly install an earlier version of Selenium or, probably better, upgrade to Python 2.6 on your Windows machine.

Comment: You nailed it,I upgraded to 2.7 shortly after i posted this question and it worked...thanks anyway !

Answer (score 3):

That installation manual seems a bit awkward to me. First, remove all files (try `pip uninstall Selenium`, or if that doesn't work just remove the `selenium` folder from your `site-packages` folder). Also, delete the single `selenium.py` file you copied.

Then, try again by running `pip install -U selenium`. If you can then open your Python prompt and do the following without errors, you're good.

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

Note that you'll also need the [Selenium server](http://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-server-standalone-2.13.0.jar), installing it as follows:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.13.0.jar
```

If all this doesn't work, clean your site-packages as before, and just download and install the files found on the [Python package index](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium). Once extracted, open a command prompt where you extracted the files and run `python setup.py install`. Then, try to import *selenium* from the command prompt again as specified above.